How to match a function but exclude object methods without negative lookbehind
I'm trying to write a regex that matches every occurrence of some_function(...), but it should not match when it's part of an object method like my.some_function(...) or if it is a substring of another function, i.e., myname_some_function(...). The function can appear in various contexts, including within another function call, after whitespace, or standalone:
Cases that should match:
some_function(...)
other_function(some_function(...))
(some_function(...))
, some_function(...)
,some_function(...)
\t some_function(...)
\n some_function(...)

Cases that should not match:
myname_some_function(...)
object.some_function(...)

Constraints:
I cannot use negative lookbehind ((?<!.)) since the environment does not support it.
The some_function should not be preceded by a dot (.) or an alphanumeric character.
What I've tried so far:
'[^.]\\s*some_function\\s*\\(.*'

This works in some cases but doesn't handle when some_function appears after parentheses, e.g., other_function(some_function(...)).
'[^.\\w]\\s*some_function\\s*\\(.*'

This excludes object methods like my.some_function(), but fails when some_function appears right after an opening parenthesis or comma (e.g., , some_function(...), (some_function(...))).

Don't use regex in this case, where you can have nested function calls.  Instead, write a parser to handle your requirement.

So are you trying to match some_function(...) alone in a line? And what's wrong with matching other_function(some_function(...)) and (some_function(...))?

Can you use lookarounds? E.g. try \b(?<!\.)some_function\s*\( (the word boundary will prevent matching where preceded with an underscore)

You could capture what you want to allow before it and capture the function part. Not sure what you want to do with it, but you could use 2 capture groups ([^.\w]|\s|^)(some_function\s*\() See https://regex101.com/r/6Fizm1/1 What is the environment that you are using, and what are you trying to accomplish?

You can use a non-capturing group and the OR operator | to match either:

A character other than one of the negated set [^...]
Exceptions to the negated set if you want to allow some part of sets like \d or \w
The beginning of a line ^

You may need to set the multiline flag /m so that matching the beginning of the line works consistently
/(?:[^\.\_\w\d]|[\(\;\)]|^)some_function/m

You can see that it matches your exampless here: regExr link
